# User sets Background Color and Font From prompt

Tags: javascript

I am trying to come up with a site that I can have the user set the background color and the font. I am able to set the color first, but when i attempt to set the font in addition it just saves over my "style" color so I am only left with the font change.
Please let me know if you guys know how to fix this issue. I have tried differnent ways to fix this problem, but obviously I still havent come up with a solution. Thank you so much for your time and consideration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function start() 
   {
    var inputColor = prompt ("Enter a color name for the " + "background of this page:");
    document.body.setAttribute("style", "background-color:" +inputColor); 
    var inputText = prompt("Enter a number to select one of the two styles:\n(1)For Serif Font\nOr\n(2) For Sans Serif Font");
    while (inputText > 2) 
    {
        var inputText = prompt("You Entered an Invalid Number!!!\n Please enter a number to select one of the two styles:\n(1)For Serif Font\nOr\n(2) For Sans Serif Font");    
    }
    if (inputText == 1) 
        document.body.setAttribute("style", "font-family: serif");
    if (inputText == 2)
        document.body.setAttribute("style", "font-family: sans-serif");
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
 </script>
 </head>
 <body> 
 <h1>Welcome To Our Customization Site</h1>
 <p>As you can see, by selecting a background color and specified text you can alter the way this site looks!</p>
<p>Just one of the many reasons our site is the best!!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, please don't give me a straight up answer, I really need to learn this, I just need some guidance in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are overwriting the `style` attribute. Try using the `style` property to manipulate styles instead of `setAttribute`.

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = inputColor
document.body.style.fontFamily = "serif";
```

By using `setAttribute` you are *setting* the value of this attribute to the value you provide as a second parameter, this means that it is going to wipe out the previous data that the attribute used to hold.

By using the `style` property JavaScript will make sure only the CSS property you change will be changed on the element and respectively its style.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I had tried that before but for some ridiculous reason I did document.body.style.backgroundColor(inputColor); & document.body.style.fontFamily = ("serif");!! Blah, thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your function:

```
function start() {
  var inputColor = prompt("Enter a color name for the " + "background of this page:");
  document.body.setAttribute("style", "background-color:" + inputColor);
  var inputText = prompt("Enter a number to select one of the two styles:\n(1)For Serif Font\nOr\n(2) For Sans Serif Font");
  while (inputText > 2) {
    var inputText = prompt("You Entered an Invalid Number!!!\n Please enter a number to select one of the two styles:\n(1)For Serif Font\nOr\n(2) For Sans Serif Font");
  }
  if (inputText == 1)
    document.body.setAttribute("style", "font-family: serif");
  if (inputText == 2)
    document.body.setAttribute("style", "font-family: sans-serif");
}
```

You use `setAttribute("style", "font-family: serif")` (among other uses), which sets the `style` *attribute* of the given DOM node to the string supplied as the second attribute (in this case `"font-family: serif"`); every time you use `setAttribute()` you over-write any previous styles you supplied.

To work around this you could either use:

```
document.body.style.fontFamily = "serif";
```

```js
function start() {
  var inputColor = prompt("Enter a color name for the " + "background of this page:");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = inputColor;
  var inputText = prompt("Enter a number to select one of the two styles:\n(1)For Serif Font\nOr\n(2) For Sans Serif Font");

  while (inputText > 2) {
    inputText = prompt("You Entered an Invalid Number!!!\n Please enter a number to select one of the two styles:\n(1)For Serif Font\nOr\n(2) For Sans Serif Font");
  }
  if (inputText == 1) {
    document.body.style.fontFamily = 'serif';
  }
  if (inputText == 2) {
    document.body.style.fontFamily = 'sans-serif';
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

```html
<h1>Welcome To Our Customization Site</h1>

<p>As you can see, by selecting a background color and specified text you can alter the way this site looks!</p>
<p>Just one of the many reasons our site is the best!!</p>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vptttef6/).

To set an individual property (that of `"font-family"`), or:

```
var currentStyles = document.getAttribute('style');

document.body.setAttribute('style', currentStyles + ' ' + 'font-family: serif');
```

```js
function start() {
  var inputColor = prompt("Enter a color name for the " + "background of this page:");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = inputColor;
  var inputText = prompt("Enter a number to select one of the two styles:\n(1)For Serif Font\nOr\n(2) For Sans Serif Font"),
    currentStyles = document.body.getAttribute('style');

  while (inputText > 2) {
    inputText = prompt("You Entered an Invalid Number!!!\n Please enter a number to select one of the two styles:\n(1)For Serif Font\nOr\n(2) For Sans Serif Font");
  }
  if (inputText == 1) {
    document.body.setAttribute('style', currentStyles + ' font-family: serif;');
  }
  if (inputText == 2) {
    document.body.setAttribute('style', currentStyles + ' font-family: sans-serif;');
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

```html
<h1>Welcome To Our Customization Site</h1>

<p>As you can see, by selecting a background color and specified text you can alter the way this site looks!</p>
<p>Just one of the many reasons our site is the best!!</p>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vptttef6/1/).

Thereby getting the previously-set values from the style attribute (`getAttribute('style')`) with the new property that you want to set.

References:

- [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).
- [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).
- [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

Comment: Wow, I didnt even think about it that way! Thank you so much for the input, extremely thorough! I will try this alternatively to see it work, thank you so much for your time!